# Laravel: passing dynamic variable thru sub-views

Tags: php, laravel, counter, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and need to pass dynamic counter to sub-views from main view. Each sub-view should use the counter value from previous sub-view. But the problem is that each sub-view initialize the counter from the beginning.
I'm using view composer to initiate the counter:

```
class PDFComposer
{

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('pdfCount', 0);
    }
}
```

Then link it to the view in my Service Provider:

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('summary', PDFComposer::class);
}
```

Then I have summary view with 4 answer sub-views:

```
@include('answer', ['answers' => $group0])
@include('answer', ['answers' => $group1])
@include('answer', ['answers' => $group2])
@include('answer', ['answers' => $group3])
```

Each sub-view updates the counter by one based on some criteria. I want next 'answer' sub-view to use the last counter value from previous 'answer' sub-view. But each view uses '0' as initial value.

Comment: Passing the counter by reference by prepending an ampersand will have all sub-view see the same variable.

Comment: Oluwafemi, I already tried this. It doesn't work in such way. The counter is initiated from '0' per each sub-view.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself. Laravel views don't intend to change the variables (logic-view separation). So, by default, all sub-views always receive initial value in isolated scope.
My solution is to link view composer with the view itself and update еру value in bi-directional mode:

- link the composer to sub-views, not main view in ServiceProvider (1*)
- update view composer to use not fixed initial value, but get value
  from view shared data (2*)
- change sub-view to update the variable at the end of rendering (3*)

.

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('answer', PDFComposer::class); // 1*
}
```

.

```
namespace App\Views\Composers;

use Illuminate\View\View;

class PDFComposer
{

    private $view;

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $this->setView($view);
        $this->view->with('pdfCount', $this->shared('pdfCount', 0)); // 2*
    }

    private function setView(View $view)
    {
        $this->view = $view;
    }

    private function shared($key, $default = null)
    {
        $sharedData = $this->view->getFactory()->getShared();
        return (isset($sharedData[$key]) ? $sharedData[$key] : $default);
    }
}
```

.

```
{{ some_blade_code_here }}
<?php view()->share('pdfCount', $pdfCount); /* 3* */ ?>
```